# What is the meaning of とか in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

ヒナさんとか一番乗りでしたね

I'm having a difficult time translating this sentence, what exactly is the function of とか in this sentence? For context, Ichika and Hina comes to the aid of a person, and later Ichika says this sentence to Hina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This とか adds a sense of "among others" or "in particular". It's used in place of the topic marker to highlight one entity among similar things. なんて also has the same meaning.

> ヒナさんとか一番乗りでしたね。
> = ヒナさんなんて一番乗りでしたね。
> Hina-san in particular was the first one to arrive, huh?

This type of とか sounds even more colloquial and slangy than なんて. It's not very suitable in business conversation.

Similar example:

- 今日とか雪まで降ったし！
  今日なんて雪まで降ったし！
  (It's been cold these days but) Today, it even snowed!

Like なんて, とか can also be used to make light of something:

- 納豆とか嫌い！
  納豆なんて嫌い！
  I hate natto!